# Deserialize JSON into C# List

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize JSON string into C# list.

The string looks like this:

```
{
    "object": {
        "key1":"",
        "key2":""
    },
    "someOtherObject": {
        "key1":"",
    },
    "anotherObject": {
        "key1":"",
        "key2":""
    }
}
```

I have tried using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` for this but it will not work since each of the objects has different name.

What would be the workaround for this so object name would be stored maybe as another key?

From what I have found, I could create object class, someOtherObject class and anotherObject class and specify their fields as well as getters and setters, which would not be a problem if only I did not have 100+ such classes to create and their structure (fields) remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary`

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

if your keys are always `key1` and `key2` you can also use a temp class like

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string Key1 { set; get; }
    public string Key2 { set; get; }
}

var dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,DummyClass>>(DATA);
```